# Fetch all links using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, chrome-web-driver

In a webpage there are 15 links that starts with similar link names which are inside an iframe. If I try to fetch those not all the links are fetched. Below are the code I tried.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(("xpath", "//*[@id='brandBand_2']/div/iframe")))
wo_link1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(("partial link text", 'SA')))
for link in wo_link1:
    print(str(link.get_attribute("href")))
```

If I manually zoom out the webpage to the maximum extent, then I am able to get all the links. Is there are any other ways to get those links without zooming out?

Comment: Provide us the url of that page.

Answer (score 0):

1. In can you did not do that - maximize the screen size with

```py
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
```

2. `visibility_of_all_elements_located` will not actually wait for all the elements matching the passed locator to be visible. Actually it waits for at least 1 element matching the passed locator to be visible and then it returns all the matching elements caught at that moment.
   You can use this method to wait for first element visibility, add some short delay and then grab all the matching links, as following:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(("xpath", "//*[@id='brandBand_2']/div/iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(("partial link text", 'SA')))
time.sleep(1)
wo_links = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'SA')
for link in wo_links:
    print(str(link.get_attribute("href")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still it is not fetching all the links!

Comment: Can you share the link to the page you are working on?

Comment: Sorry! that is a Salesforce link which requires Username and Password.

Comment: I understand. But without minimal debugging it's hard to help...

Comment: Can I provide html codes?

Comment: I'm not sure I will be able to debug that. Maybe someone else.